# Where is my torrc on OS X for Tor Browser Bundle 6.0.6?

Tags: configuration, mac

I couldn't find an answer for this but I discovered it by running TBB Firefox from the command line so I'm putting it here with an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Tor puts user specific configuration in:

```
~/Library/Application Support/TorBrowser-Data
```

So for the user guest the torrc file is:

```
/Users/guest/Library/Application Support/TorBrowser-Data/Tor/torrc
```

Note that this file will be empty or might not exist unless you have made some changes from the default.